# How to insert image which is taken from a form and store into a database as bytes using C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert some data including an image (as bytes) into a database. How can I do this?

```
Stream fs = img.ImageFile.PostedFile.InputStream;

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

This above is what I have tried

Comment: Why use fs.Lenght instead of just fs?

Comment: actually i dont know y.I just pasted from net.am new to mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get file byte

```
byte[] file = new byte[img.ImageFile.PostedFile.ContentLength];
```

Your query(as template)

```
insert into table file values @file
new SqlParameter("@file",file)
```

New code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addimage(HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile) 
{ 
  byte[] file = new byte[ImageFile.ContentLength];
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
  { 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.addimage", con)) 
    { 
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", file);
      con.Open(); 
      status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.ImageFile is of the type HttpPostedFile,and it shows an error on "new byte[img.ImageFile.PostedFile.ContentLength];" that System.web.HttpPostedFile does not contain a definition for "PostedFile" .How could i solve this?

Comment: You marked as resolve. Do you still have this problem?

Comment: Could you show your action code? How you get model or property?

Comment: [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addimage(image img)
    {
    
        

        byte[] file = new byte[img.ImageFile.PostedFile.ContentLength];

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.addimage", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", img.timage);
                con.Open();
                status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

Comment: @JilneshAjayJîllu in a future you able to update you main answer, add new code, update) In comment this code looks bad

Comment: Could you replace you image on HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: @ evilGenius .sir am new to mvc.i dont know how to insert image into database as bytes.please help me

Comment: and my model is like this:                                                                                 public class image 
    {
        public string timage { get; set; } 
        public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Ok, add your view

Comment: and my view code is :@Html.BeginForm("addimage","home",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
{
<input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
}

Comment: @JilneshAjayJîllu dude, you really work with mvc first time?) You just need return some View("YourView");. Because it's not void it actionResult type return value.

Comment: yes sir.is there any built in function to display this image

Comment: @JilneshAjayJîllu i really glad to heard it. Good luck to learning mvc)